# Is it possible to dynamically load images to the plc s7-1200?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, plc, s7-1200

I have the following situation:
I have a cam that takes a photo every 5 seconds and saves the last 5 photos in an image folder, and an html page with a JS that processes the colours of those images after loading them in the page and also sends the results through ajax to the plc.

The thing is that when I execute the program directly from the browser it runs well.
But when I try to run it from the PLC all the code has to be converted into blocks, and this seems to include the images as well.
If I turn all the content of the program (with the images included) it also runs well, but the images doesn't update in real time like in the browser.
If I only turn the .html into blocks but not the images, then the program can't load the images at all and it does nothing.

Is there a library to directly load a .jpg image in real timeto the plc or a way to turn the .jpg images to blocks in real time?
If that's not possible, should I build a local server and do the processing there, and call it through ajax?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The solution I'm working on: sharing the folder from my PC so the PLC can access it.
Any tips on how I could do that? Thanks!

Comment: why would you like to send the images to the PLC? Is it going to process it somehow or is a still image for a HMI device? IMHO, processing images on a PC is preferred because it has computing power. PLC's are devices that handle async I/O signals.